# How to include my codes in a blue box?

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown

I want to bring a code in my question. I've seen this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), but I didn't find any solution here.
How to include my codes in a blue box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the fine suggestions given by Asaf, you can include your code inline in backquotes $ ^\grave{}\dots^\grave{}$ like this `$e=e^1$`.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean like that:

> $e=e^1$.

Or do you mean like that:

```
$e=e^1$.
```

---

The former is done by adding `>` at the beginning of the line, and the latter is done by typing **four** whitespaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #0000FF]{\text{Evidently, they didn't mean something like this.}}$

Comment: @robjohn: I didn't even know that the box was blue until now.

Comment: I think the color of the highlighting depends on the visual theme of the site. Here I see it as $\bbox[5px,border:0px solid #0000FF,#EEEEEE]{\text{a background of gray: }\mathrm{0xEEEEEE}}$

Comment: @robjohn: I too believe it depends on the theme. I'm just not very good with colors, and not once I have mistaken light shades of blue to be gray of some sort.

Comment: @robjohn: Could you please provide the code for your text in the blue box?

Comment: @LePressentiment: you can always see the MathJax source by right-clicking on the rendered MathJax and selecting "Show Math As > TeX Commands"

Comment: @robjohn: Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Granting that the OP quested after the box in [robjohn's post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10210/how-to-include-my-codes-in-a-blue-box#comment37612_10211), with many thanks to robjohn, I promulgate it explicitly:

`\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #0000FF]{\text{ STUFF HERE }}`

Comment: When you mention *robjohn's post*, readers might assume that you mean his answer. (Answers are more visible than comments). Saying that you mean *robjohn's comment* would be, in my opinion, less ambiguous. (This was the reason why I've added a link to the comment.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks for the edit!